# RxJS not all Subscribers receive all events

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactivex, reactive

I'm working on an exercise about RxJS.
And there's something very strange happening:

```
  typoStream.subscribe(x => console.log('wont get executed'));
  wordCompletedStream.subscribe(nextStream);
  typoStream.subscribe(x => console.log('will get executed'));
```

When the application runs the first console.log won't get printed and the second one will.
Regardless of what the streams are and how they interact - this should never happen, right? Why is it important when I subscribe to an observable - shouldn't it emit the event to every subscriber anyways?

If you want to try it:
http://embed.plnkr.co/xb8Yimo5RcYGPtgClYgY/

Type the displayed word correctly and you can see the "error" in action. But it doesn't happen every time - only most of the time.

Here's the stream flow: https://photos.app.goo.gl/Z4cpKzekAIuKzMF93

Comment: Would you be so kind, please, and copy everything for us? And provide us with an example with the minimum of code?

Comment: Well, typoStream has a filter on it, so it only emits when there's a typo. If you don't make a typo, it should never fire. If you do make a typo, both subscribes fire. And I think it has a flaw in the return statement when input is empty, making it fire on a new word.

Comment: Hi, I tried to reduce the code as much as possible: http://embed.plnkr.co/xb8Yimo5RcYGPtgClYgY/
I made a graph how the data flows: https://photos.app.goo.gl/Z4cpKzekAIuKzMF93

Comment: @RichardMatsen Where's the flaw in the return statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a play with the code you posted, and the key fix is to properly multicast the `checkWord` observable. You can do this with `.publish().refCount()` like you did for `wordStream`, or you can use the shortcut method that does the same thing, `.share()`.

```
  const checkStream = wordStream.combineLatest(inputStream).share();
```

The reason this works is that without it, multiple subscriptions to `checkStream` or any streams derived from it, such as `typoStream` and `wordCompletedStream` will each trigger a new subscription to the `wordStream` observable (which is correctly multicast, so no new request gets made) and the `inputStream` observable, which will register new event listeners on the input.

With the `.share()` operator, it doesn't matter how many subscriptions are made to `checkStream` or derived observables, only the first one will trigger a subscription to `inputStream`.

Note that after this fix, neither of the two subscribers to `typoStream` will fire for a correctly entered word. Which is what I would expect from an observable called `typoStream`. Both will fire when an incorrect character is entered.

[Forked Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6uUA1Vdt5mvgjXUlXdre?p=preview)

Or see the snippet below:

```js
(() => {

  // --- UI Stuff, NO NEED TO TOUCH THESE --- //
  const wordField = $('#TotDWord');
  const inputField = $('#TotDInput');
  // ----------------------------------------- //

  // A stream of the users string inputs
  const inputFieldStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(inputField, 'keyup')
    .map(x => x.target.value).distinctUntilChanged();

  // This stream is used to represent the users unput - we don't use the 
  // inputFieldStream directly because we want to manually send values aswell
  const inputStream = new Rx.Subject();


  // Feed the stream from the field into our inputStream
  inputFieldStream.subscribe(inputStream);

  // A stream that allows us to manually trigger that we need a new word
  const nextStream = new Rx.Subject();

  // When we want the next word we need to reset the users input
  nextStream.subscribe(() => {
    inputField.val('');
    inputStream.onNext('');
  });

  // This stream calls a server for a new random word every time the nextStream emits an event. We startWith a value to trigger the first word
  const wordStream = nextStream.startWith('')
    .flatMapLatest(getRandomWord)
    // publish & refCount cache the result - otherwise every .map on wordStream would cause a new HTTP request
    .publish().refCount();

  // When there is a new word, we display it
  wordStream.subscribe(word => {
    wordField.empty();
    wordField.append(word);
  });

  // Checkstream combines the latest word with the latest userinput. It emits an array, like this ['the word', 'the user input'];
  const checkStream = wordStream.combineLatest(inputStream).share();

  // Emits an event if the user input is not correct
  const typoStream = checkStream.filter(tuple => {
    const word = tuple[0];
    const input = tuple[1];
    return !word.startsWith(input);
  });

  // When there is a typo we need a new word
  typoStream.subscribe(nextStream);

  // Emits an event when the user has entered the entire word correctly
  const wordCompletedStream = checkStream.filter(tuple => {
    const word = tuple[0];
    const input = tuple[1];
    return word == input;
  });

  /**
   * THIS WILL (MOST OF THE TIME) NOT FIRE WHEN YOU COMPLETE A WORD
   */
  typoStream.subscribe(x => console.log('wont get executed'));

  // Whenever the word is completed, request a new word
  wordCompletedStream.subscribe(nextStream);

  /**
   * THIS WILL FIRE WHEN YOU COMPLETE A WORD
   */
  typoStream.subscribe(x => console.log('will get executed'));

  // Calls a server for a random word
  // returns a promise
  function getRandomWord() {
    return $.ajax({
      // Change the URL to cause a 404 error
      url: 'https://setgetgo.com/randomword/get.php'
    }).promise();
  }

})();
```

```html
<script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.6/rx.all.js"></script>

<div>
  <h1>Exercise: Typing of the Dead</h1>
  <div>
    Type the given word correctly and watch the console. Most of the time 1 of the 2 subscriptions on the typoStream will fire (when there should fire none).
  </div>
  <br />
  <div id="TotDWord"></div>
  <input type="text" name="" id="TotDInput" value="" /><span>Highscore: </span><span id="TotDHighscore"></span>
  <div id="TotDScore"></div>
</div>

<script>
  console.clear();
</script>
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! But I have to admin, I don't quite understand why it's behaving the way it is - especially since it wouldn't behave the same every time. Why does a new subscription on the inputStream emit the value from the inputFieldStream instead of the empty value that's been emity via inputStream.onNext('') ?