# rxjava Why are not all the subscribers picking the event?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, observer-pattern, observers, reactivex

I have been working on building a system where I watch on a socket for messages and send out to the subscribers. The subscribers will then process the message if its for them, that can be known from the message sent to them. I believe this can be achieved using rxjava.

The problem I'm facing is, say,

I have two subscribers, and for message number 123, only one of them are notified `not both`. 
I'm a rxjava/reactive programming newbie.

**CODE :**

I have clients connected using

```
public void getClientConnections(ServerSocket clientSocket, Flowable<EventData> events) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Socket socket = clientSocket.accept();
        Observable.just(socket).subscribeOn(scheduler).subscribe((x) -> {
                String userId = readValueFromInputStream(socket);
                UserData ud = new UserData(socket);
                ud.userId = userId;
events.observeOn(scheduler).subscribeOn(scheduler).subscribe((event) -> {
                    processMessageAtClient(ud, event);
                });
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The `Flowable<EventData> events` is from below

```
public Flowable<EventData> getEvents(Socket eventSocket) throws IOException {
    Flowable<EventData> flowable = Flowable.create((source) -> {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(eventSocket.getInputStream()));
        while (!source.isCancelled()) {

            String inputLine = in.readLine();
            if (inputLine != null && !inputLine.isEmpty()) {
                source.onNext(new EventData(inputLine));
            }
            // emitter.onError(new Throwable("SOMETHING WRONG"));
        }
    }, BackpressureStrategy.ERROR).map(model -> {
        processInputLine((EventData) model);
        return (EventData) model;
    }).filter(model -> {
        return (model.eventType != null);
    });
    return flowable;
}
```

The Thread details are

```
ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(threadPoolExecutor);
```

**UPDATE**

```
private void processMessageAtClient(UserData ud, EventData event) {

    Socket socket = ud.socket;
    String userId = ud.userId;
    if (event.toUserId.equals(userId))) {
        PrintWriter out;
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            sortedEvents.poll();
            incrementCount();
            out.println(event.inputLine);
            System.out.println("Sending " + event.inputLine);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are those subscribers you are talking about? Also why are you recreating stream and buffered readers in a loop? How is the `events` input to the connection-accepting code if it `getEvent` depends on the socket? What does `processMessageAtClient` do with the events?

Comment: @akarnokd Thanks a lot for noticing `recreating stream and buffered readers in a loop` have correct it. `processMessageAtClient` In this method, all the the subscribers will check if this event is for them if not ignore it else do something.

Comment: Please provide the code of `processMessageAtClient` and please detail how events are distributed to subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `.share()` to the Flowable in my `getEvents` method. 
you can use `.publish().refCount()` too its all the same.

This should be provided if you need to multicast the event to all the subscribers.

Could be a Duplicate of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47253361/rxjs-not-all-subscribers-receive-all-events) But this is in Javascript.